# What equation could you use to model the shape of a thread when held at 2 ends?

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity, string

If you were to hold a string at both ends what shape would the string take(in earth's gravity). Obviously this depends on the length of string and the distance you hold the 2 ends apart so let's say that you can only change the distance of the ends from one another on a straight line parallel to the ground. What equation could you use to predict the shape of the string at any given length(of the string) and distance(of the ends)?

Comment: Assuming just gravity (no blowing on the thread :-) ), the first approximation would be a [catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary).

Comment: @NickD thank you, I tried searching it up before but I just didn't have the words to articulate what I was looking for to google. I figured this was already a well known thing.

Comment: I posted my answer thinking you wanted the physical equation to model the string, haha didn’t know you just wanted the mathematical description of it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equation for a string fixed at both ends without simplifying assumptions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402950/what-is-the-equation-for-a-string-fixed-at-both-ends-without-simplifying-assumpt)

Comment: Not really what you asked but pretty cool https://www.myphysicslab.com/engine2D/chain-en.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/279247/268448

Comment: @JustJohan thank you I enjoyed playing around with it.

Comment: @JAlex thank you, I looked around a bit to see if I could find a similar question but I didn't see that one otherwise I wouldn't have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the [**Catenary**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#:%7E:text=In%20physics%20and%20geometry%2C%20a,it%20is%20not%20a%20parabola.) shape?

The general equation is

$$ y(x) = a \left( \cosh \left( \tfrac{x}{a} \right) -1 \right) $$

where $y(0)=0$ is the lowest point on the curve, and the parameter $a$ defines how much it bends.

What remains constant along the curve is the horizontal component of tension $H$, which can be used to find $a$

$$ a = \frac{H}{w} $$

where $w$ is the *weight* per unit length.