# Deriving Potential Energy Density for Longitudinally Vibrating String

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy, continuum-mechanics, vibrations, string

I understand how to derive the density for a string vibrating transversely. However, for a longitudinal one, I had some doubts.

Namely, suppose $ y(x,t) $ is the extension of some point (really, infinitesimal interval) on the string.
The kinetic energy density is $$ K = \frac{1}{2} \rho (\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})^2 $$ where $\rho$ - linear mass density.

To derive the potential energy density, I am considering the work done against $T$, the tension force of the string.

$$W = T \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$

Using this logic, the potential density should be

$$V = T \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}$$

It seems that there should be a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ in the potential density as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: " extension of some point " Don't you mean lateral displacement?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106056/2451